# How to record requests from client in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I have a Java desktop application. I want to know if there is a way to record server calls (`GET` & `POST` requests) using Gatling where requests will be generated from desktop application. I am trying to use Gatling for load testing.

Comment: By "record" do you mean you want to log from Gatling? Have you tried configuring it's logback?

Comment: I mean Gatling recorder captures all request and responses when we configure the web browser and creates simulation for the same. I want to create the simulations for a desktop application (not web browser). I hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Hmm I think you will have to configure the desktop application to proxy through the Gatling recorder...